# Delayed update in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: performance, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a simple PL/SQL procedure, with one cursor and I iterate over it. In each iteration I make an UPDATE statement (after performing some business logic to the data).

However, if there are lots of iterations (tens of thousands), this can get pretty slow, because in every iteration there is single UPDATE statement.

Is there a way to somehow "delay" those updates so that they are executed all at once (and thus much faster).

Edit: Oracle 11

Comment: Well, the problem is that Oracle maintains its rollback segment. The more you modify in one transaction, the slower it gets. Can't you split up the business logic and add a `COMMIT;` every 1000 `UPDATE`s or so?

Comment: @sjngm, this is generally a Bad Idea. Tom Kyte has plenty to say about it, e.g., http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4951966319022.

Comment: @snjgm, the slowdown is not because of rollback segments, its caused by the iterations and the selects. The updates to the rollback segments are negligible compared to the other work that is executed as it sounds

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you can't figure out how to use straight SQL (avoiding the for loop all together) then you will likely be able to improve performance using the BULK Collection features of pl/sql.

[Example article here.](http://www.dbspecialists.com/files/presentations/bulk_binds.html)

**Syntax excerpt**

```
 LOOP
    FETCH c_orders
    BULK COLLECT INTO v_order_ids, v_currency_codes, v_amounts_local
    LIMIT 100;
    EXIT WHEN v_row_count = c_orders%ROWCOUNT;
    v_row_count := c_orders%ROWCOUNT;
    FOR i IN 1..v_order_ids.count LOOP
      v_amounts_usd(i) := currency_convert (v_amounts_local(i),
                                            v_currency_codes(i));
    END LOOP;
    FORALL i IN 1..v_order_ids.count
      UPDATE open_orders /* bulk bind */
      SET    amount_usd = v_amounts_usd(i)
      WHERE  order_id = v_order_ids(i);
  END LOOP;
```

Comment: +1 came here to give the same answer. also an other article on forall http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_rittman_bulk%20binds_FORALL.htm

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any analysis of what the problem is, but I see people making a lot assumptions and jumping to conclusions. To get a more systematic approach I recommend the following:

- Enable 10046 level tracing for the session when the update job runs to see where most of the time is spent
- Get session level statistics before the update job is run and afterwards.

See where most of the time is spent and tackle the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try if at all possible to perform the business logic in the update statement.  It will be a lot faster.